# How can I send a unique id or email and password to the user's e-mail?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, authentication

I have an application and on a page in this application there is another page that I need to redirect via an id or email and password sent to the user's e-mail. I need to send this random information to the e-mail the user used while registering, and the user should not log in to this page with any other email or password other than this information. I am using Firebase as database.

Comment: If you need to code that in Kotlin, then I think that this article, [How to handle Firebase Authentication in clean architecture using Jetpack Compose?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-handle-firebase-authentication-in-clean-architecture-using-jetpack-compose-e9929c0e31f8), might help.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is pretty much exactly what Firebase Authentication's [email link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth) provider does, so I recommend checking that out.